# Instant run нужно ли?

Tags: android, android-studio

Всё чаще Android Studio предлагает сделать update Instant Run 2.2.2. Пролистав о возможностях, выделил для себя что это способствует быстрому запуску приложения, без предварительной установки apk.

Но на самом деле это так хорошо как описывают?

И если да, как его установить так, чтоб он не всплывал мне каждый раз окном.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instant Run – это технология, позволяющая сократить время сборки проекта (*при этом время первой сборки увеличивается*).

**Но есть одно очень большое НО**: при использовании этой технологии, в некоторых случаях Вы можете получить некорректное поведением Ваших программ.

В официальной документации Google сам пишет что-то вроде: «... для корректного функционирования *название_чего-то* технология `Instant Run` должна быть отключена».

Если Вы знаете *все те ситуации*, где использование `Instant Run` может привести к некорректным результатам, то в принципе, использовать ее можно, но что-то мне подсказывает, что использование этой технологии может повлиять на поведение Вашей программы даже в каком-то случае, который незадокументирован, поэтому **я все таки посоветовал бы не использовать ее** (по крайней мере пока).

Подробнее про `Instant Run` можно почитать в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/company/livetyping/blog/304640/), либо в официальной документации.

**UPD.** Как отключить Instant Run:

`File` – `Settings` – `Build, Execution, Deployment` – `Instant Run` – убрать галочку `Enable Instant Run...`

Comment: Работает — не трогай. :)

Comment: @post_zeew понял, спасибо. А как всё таки выключить его вместе с вечно всплывающими окнами запустить приложение посредством Instant Run?

Comment: @Inkognito, Смотрите **UPD**.

Answer (score 1):

`Instant Run` - ужасная технология, без конца приводившая к непонятным багам, которые можно было объяснить только в области иррационального или через метафизику. При первой возможности этот пункт надо было скорее отключать, чтобы не просидеть над совершенно невероятным багом несколько часов. Также Instant Run влиял на поведение библиотек, да и много всего вытворял (об этом регулярно писали в комментариях на SO).

Свершилось чудо, и его убрали из Android Studio 3.5. Теперь это `Apply Changes`, см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616439/instant-run-is-missing-in-android-studio-3-5.